# Javascript doesn't work on heroku in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a javascript code that should display image (loading gif) when you click to create a comment. It works in development, but not when I deploy it to heroku. I am able to make the most js/css files work properly, but not in this case.

```
<%= nested_form_for([@post, @comment], validate: true, html: {multipart: true}, 'data-update-target' => 'comments', class: 'comments') do  |f| %>

...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit " Submit ", :class => "btn btn-default", :id => "submit" %>
  </div><br>

  <div id="loading2" class="loadinggif" style="display:none;"><img src="/assets/othericons/uploading.gif" alt="" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function (d) {
  d.getElementById('new_comment').onsubmit = function () {
    d.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
    d.getElementById('loading2').style.display = 'block';
  };
}(document));
</script>
```

**solution**

I changed

```
  <div id="loading2" class="loadinggif" style="display:none;"><img src="/assets/othericons/uploading.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

to

```
    <div id="loading2" class="loadinggif" style="display:none;">
      <%= image_tag("othericons/uploading.gif", alt: "") %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check that the uploading.gif is accessible, my guess is that this has something to do with the path there since you are not using `asset_path` to generate the url.

Answer (score 1):

With Heroku, I've only had success pre-compiling assets and adding those assets to git before deploying. When I start working on any assets in my dev environment, I run `rake assets:clean` and then when I'm done, `rake assets:precompile; git add --all public/assets`.

Comment: everybody says the same point as yours, yet it does not work for me :(